# Jmeter thread groups

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have entered 500 to be the number of thread group and ramp up time to be 120 seconds but when the report is generated,the virtual users count is only 15 or in composite graph-active threads over time is raised to near about 12. So I am bit confuse active threads counts. Because the data(threads) or numbers that I filled in test plan before test is different and after result is different. What about scaled values in graph?and x10?Something related to threads?

Comment: your threads likely finish quickly and exit before all the other threads become active. Try checking the "forever" checkbox for loop count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each JMeter thread representing a virtual user after initialization starts executing samplers upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)).

If thread doesn't have more samplers to execute and no more loops to iterate it's being shut down. It looks just like your case. See [Max Users is Lower than Expected](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/147922-max-users-is-lower-than-expected) article for more detailed explanation and workaround.

Usually people set Loop Count to "Forever" and use [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) to so test could finish in designed time. Another option is using i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) which provides convenient way of defining a load scenario.